# Пауза в setInterval во время выполнения

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Возникла такая проблема, функция каждую секунду делает проверку, но если возникает исключение в `PHP-коде`, мне надо приостановить `setInterval` на 60 секунд, а после этого восстановить его проверку каждую секунду. Как такое можно реализовать?

```js
function show() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#content").html(data);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval('show()', 1000);
});
```

Comment: Если вместо конкретного времени задержки (1000мс) подставить переменную которая будет динамически изменяться в зависимости какие data пришли с сервера и пришли ли, пробовали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, возвращать с сервера JSON, в котором, если выброшено исключение `isException = true`. Пример клиента:

```js
var interval;

function show() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      let object = JSON.parse(data);

      if (object.isException) {
        restartInterval()
      }

      $("#content").html(data.html);
    },
    error: function() { // если выброшена 500, например, ошибка, будет вызван этот метод.
      restartInterval()
    }
  });
}

function restartInterval() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  setTimeout(() => interval = setInterval(show, 1000), 60000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  interval = setInterval(show, 1000);
});
```